# Selenium - Locating elements - onunload=ajaxUnload

Tags: ajax, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to locate elements from a web site. However WebDriver seems not to be able to load elements after an `onunload=ajaxUnload()` tag.

Any help or hint how we can "refresh" the WebDriver after an internal program dynamically changes the elements of a web site?

I have tried with explicit and implicit waits but it doesn't work (I have waited 5 minutes). It is not a new frame neither window.

If it helps the code is similar to:

```
<*html>

<*head>

<*body onunload="ajaxUnload();" class="test">

<*script>

<*div id="selection">
```

Comment: are you running into StaleStateExceptions ?

Comment: Hi Greg Webdriver is throwing an exception if I try to locate an element below the ajaxUnload();. Following the example on my post Web driver is not able to find the element id=selection. Hope this has answered your question. Cheers Will